# Kitchen cupboard replacement hinges too close: How to fix?

Tags: replacement, hinges

I've replaced the hinges on my kitchen cabinet doors because the spring in the old ones broke.  [I've used these as they were closest to the old hinge type.](https://www.cabinetparts.com/p/salice-hinges-european-cabinet-hinges-SHCSP37XR#reviews)

Unfortunately, the two cupboard doors are now too close together and won't close. Even if I use the adjustments on the new hinges, the doors are still too close together. The overlap seems to be slightly over 6mm / a quarter of an inch.

I'm thinking I might have to inlay where the new hinges are mounted to the cupboard frame, but this seems a bit drastic.

Are there any better ideas?

[image: Where the doors are.]

[image: New hinges.]

Comment: Could you add some pictures?

Comment: @Jon Done! Let me know if something else will help.

Comment: You really have two options. You can shift the mortise like you suggested, or you can find more suitable hinges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your doors are overlapping, you simply need another set of hinges with a larger overlay. The hinges in the link are 1/2" overlay and if that is what you are using there, you need to get a set of hinges with a 3/4" overlay. These are also known as "full overlay" hinges

Comment: Finally got around to installing them an the 3/4" overlay did the trick. Thank-you!